# NoVNC and cyrrilic symbols

Tags: javascript, vnc

I am using noVNC in my project. But now I found some strange behavior: if you enter some other non-english characters, they are entered wrong in noVNC console. Is that a bug or did I missconfigured anything?

Comment: It seems there is a problem with some non-ascii keys in noVnc ... I am alos struggling. Did you find anything ?

Comment: Well, the upgrade of the noVNC lib might help

Comment: did that solve it ? I have an old old version that is working atm

Comment: well don't know really, haven't tried that yet

Comment: Upgrade of noVNC worked for us.